# SpiderMonkey 24: How to call Reflect.parse()?

Tags: javascript, c++, parsing, spidermonkey

According to the [Parser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API) you can call `Reflect.parse()` to get an AST back. Unfortunately, when trying to evaluate a script in C++ it gives me an error saying `ReferenceError: Reflect is not defined`:

```
const char *script = "var r = Reflect.parse(\"obj.foo + 42\");";
bool ok = JS_EvaluateScript(cx, global, script, strlen(script), filename, lineno, rval.address());
```

Actually, I want to parse some simple JS Scripts and get the AST within C++, I don't like the way doing a detour and having it analyzed in JS itself. Do you have any suggestions? The documentation is not very good imho.

I tried using `JS_CompileScript()`, but it seems like 1) the members of `JSScript` class are not visible when using the compiled lib 2) don't have information about the tree anymore (?).

I'm tempted to use the very old version 1.6 as there is a very nice [parsing tutorial](http://siliconforks.com/doc/parsing-javascript-with-spidermonkey/) out there. What are your thoughts about that?

Another way would be not to compile SpiderMonkey and use the Parser classes directly.

Any hints/suggestions in what the best way (in your opinion) would be are highly appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

> Actually, I want to parse some simple JS Scripts and get the AST within C++, I don't like the way doing a detour and having it analyzed in JS itself. Do you have any suggestions?

If patching the Monkey is (was) an option for you, I have a possible approach. I'm doing this with SpiderMonkey 45, but the Reflect API already existed in 24.

In `ReflectParse.cpp:3593`, there's the function

```
static bool reflect_parse(JSContext* cx, uint32_t argc, Value* vp)
```

Make that non-static and declare it in `jsapi.h` like this:

```
extern JS_PUBLIC_API(bool) reflect_parse(JSContext* cx, uint32_t argc, JS::Value* vp);
```

Actually, this is copy/paste from the `JS_InitReflectParse` declaration in said file. Now you can call the C implementation of `Reflect.parse()` from outside.

You'll also need a bunch of private headers, I currently include these: `builtin/ModuleObject.h`, `jscntxt.h`, `jscompartment.h`, `jsobj.h`, `frontend/ParseNode.h`

The `Value* vp` that `reflect_parse` expects as second parameter is a `JS::AutoValueArray<3>` constructed as follows:

- Index 0 will later hold a `JSValue` to the returned object. `CallArgs::rval()` retrieves it from there.
- Index 1 holds some kind of a magic number. Don't touch. (Setting it to something resulted in an assertion for me.)
- Index 2 holds another `JS::AutoValueArray<n>` that contains the parameters for `Reflect.parse`.

So for a simple call like `Reflect.parse(code)`, the parameters can look like this:

```
JS::RootedString codeJsStr(context); // Empty string for now
JS::AutoValueArray<1> parseParams(context);
parseParams[0].setString(codeJsStr);
JS::AutoValueArray<3> vp(m_context);
vp[2].set(*parseParams.begin());
reflect_parse(m_context, parseParams.length(), vp.begin());
```

The return value can then be processed with help of `CallArgs` just like it is documented for calling js functions from C.